# How to keep program running until user types stop?

Tags: c++

I built my first C++ software that asks the user to put in a price and discount and then the program shows the total amount including tax after discount.

I want to keep the program running until the user types `stop`, or anything specific I write. But I don't want the program to ask the user if they want to run the program again. It should keep running until the user types in a specific command.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // declaring integers
    int bill; 
    int discount;
    cout << "\n\t**************************************************************\n";
    cout << "\t\t    D i s c o u n t  &  T a x   C a l c u l a t o r\n";
    cout << "\t**************************************************************\n";

    cout << "Enter the Amount $";
    //asking user to put in the amount
    cin >> bill;
    cout << "Enter the Discount(%) ";
    //asking user to put in discount percent
    cin >> discount;
    int NewPrice = round(bill-(bill*discount/100));
    cout << "Your dicounted price is $" << NewPrice <<endl;
    cout << "Your Total Bill is " << round(NewPrice * 8.875) / (100) + (NewPrice);
    
    //shows the total value 
    cout << round(bill + discount);
    
    cout << "\n\t**************************************************************\n";
    cout << "\t\t               T H A N K  Y O U\n";
    cout << "\t**************************************************************\n"; 
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: done plz chck. thnx

Comment: "*How to keep program running until user types stop?*" - use a loop

Comment: While(true){do stuff};

Comment: BTW, in `return 0; system("pause");`, the `system()` command will never be exeecuted. Reverse the order of those two expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an indefinite loop in one of two ways:

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
for (;;) {
    ...
}
```

In both cases the test always passes, so nothing about this stops the loop.

You can then use a conditional within the loop and either `break` or `return` to interrupt control flow and exit the loop.

```
while (true) {
    if (cond) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*You can get an indefinite loop in one of **two** ways*" - 3 ways, if you include `do/while`, eg: `do { ... } while (true);` 4 ways, if you include `goto`, eg: `label: ... goto label;`